# Is mandatory to unregister prometheus collector?

Tags: java, prometheus

Is prometheus collector unregistration from collector registry mandatory before shutting down jvm? Code sample below.

```
CollectorRegistry myRegistry = new MyCollectorRegistry();
Collector counter = Counter.build().name("req_cnt").create();
myRegistry.register(counter);
// somewhere in destroy method, is this mandatory?
myRegistry.unregister(counter);
```

Comment: Why do you think this would matter if the JVM exits?

Answer (score 0):

No, unregistering is something that should only come up in rare unittests.