# Best practice for unregistering/redefining/customizing already-registered Prometheus metrics in Java

Tags: java, prometheus, prometheus-java

Say I'm using a library (Java) which defines / registers metrics in Prometheus. I'm wondering how I might be able to unregister/redefine/customize these metrics which have already been defined/registered by said library? Specifically, if I had a Histogram with certain buckets that were already registered, how could I update the same Histogram with different buckets?

For example, if `my-java-library` defines a `Histogram` with name `my_histogram`, I was thinking I might be able to use the `unregister` method on [CollectorRegistry](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/io/prometheus/client/CollectorRegistry.html#unregister(io.prometheus.client.Collector)) like so:

in `my-java-library`:

```
{
...

this.myHistogram = Histogram.build()
    .name("my_histogram")
    .register();

...
}

public Histogram getMyHistogram() {
    return this.myHistogram;
}
```

in `my-repo` that uses `my-java-library`:

```
import my-java-library; // ignore the poor naming convention :^)

...

{
...

    Histogram myHistogram = myJavaLibrary.getMyHistogram();
    CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.unregister(myHistogram);

...
}
```

The above example seems to be problematic for a few reasons:

1. The `unregister` method is apparently only supposed to be used in rare cases for unit tests and not (apparently) for the above purpose ([[1](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/248#issuecomment-366535493)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869734/3905007)], [[3](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/pull/555#issuecomment-630698597)])
2. It seems the client_java repo for Prometheus is registering background, inaccessible  metrics behind the scenes which, since these `Collector` instances aren't accessible (at least not to my knowledge), cannot be `unregister`ed using the aforementioned model. This means even if I tried and succeeded at unregistering `my_histogram`, I will still run into a runtime exception ([IllegalArgumentException](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/CollectorRegistry.java#L67-L75)) since these behind-the-scene metrics are being caught by the `assertNoDuplicateNames` method.

I'm at a bit of a loss. I will probably create an issue in the client_java repo as well but wanted to see if anyone on SO has run into and solved this problem for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that `my-java-library` will use the `this.myHistogram` instance. So unregistering `this.myHistogram` does not help because the library will just continue using the unregistered `this.myHistogram` instance, but you would never see these metrics as the histogram is no longer registered.

What you could try is to replace `this.myHistogram` with your own instance. If the library has a setter `myJavaLibrary.setMyHistogram(Histogram)` that should work, if it doesn't you will likely need to use reflection to replace the `this.myHistogram` instance in the library.

This is not directly related to unregistering the original `myHistogram` instance. You can just register your own instance with a different name and keep the original instance registered. You can use `CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.unregister(myHistogram)` for unregistering the original instance, but this is just for cleaning up and should not affect functionality, because after setting `this.myHistogram` the library will not be able to access the original instance and the original instance will never be used.

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing details in my initial question.


To address your first point/paragraph about `my-java-library` and `this.myHistogram`: the plan after the `unregister` call was to once again register `this.myHistogram` on the `defaultRegistry` (which I believe should be shared across the `my-java-library` and `my-repo`), except from within `my-repo` with the customizations. One added benefit of `my-java-library` that was not mentioned is it would do some overhead work with registering certain endpoints against `this.myHistogram`, after `this.myHistogram` has been properly re-registered

Comment: Point/Paragraph 2: I was under the impression that something like `setMyHistogram` wouldn't work because simply redefining an instance variable circumvents the static `defaultRegistry`/`CollectorRegistry` (hence the need to `unregister`). Is that not accurate? I'm not very familiar with reflections, but I think I will address this point about a solution in my final comment.

Comment: [1/2] Point/Paragraph 3: Using a new / different-name metric was discussed but this pattern of customizing metrics defined within `my-java-library` kept cropping up, hence wanting to modify this existing metric.

It also seems that client_java is [creating other metrics (Gauges) for Histograms behind-the-scenes](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/989cbd1f4f249d84dbdf4b9e91b9676cc64022b6/simpleclient/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/Collector.java#L168-L175)?

Comment: [2/2] But to your point about instances, I guess I'm a bit confused by how that works -- the library won't be able to access the original instance even if it's saved as a field member? I thought metrics were also identifiable by their names against the CollectorRegistry? Perhaps not..

Comment: As for a path forward: in my case, I am a bit lucky in that `my-java-library` is a repo that I can make changes to, so for this particular instance what I decided to do was expose the `Builder`s for all the default metrics in `my-java-library` first, which should allow me to intercept them and customize them how I want before they are actually `register`ed. As one takeaway from this entire discussion, I think either some support or alternatively clarification for best practices on registering/(not) re-registering could be added.

Comment: Sorry for all the reading; thanks so much for your input!